# Can SSRS matrix be used to sum aggregates?

Tags: reporting-services

Using SSRS I created a matrix that displays, let's say, CountDistinct(Student) for each Class.  I need to count distinct because attendance is taken twice (at beginning of class and after a break), and the goal of the report is simply to see if the student attended the class that day.

The columns are the days in the date range selected by the user and the rows are the user selected values for Class(es).  The problem is that I would like the Total row to reflect a sum of all values (e.g. Jan 2 as shown below should total 7).  Instead I am getting the value of CountDistinct(Student) in the Total row as well. The problem with this is that some students will take multiple classes, so counting DISTINCT won't represent their attendance in both classes.

What I'm getting:

```
Attendance for...

[Class]             [Jan 2]     [Jan 3]
----------------    --------    --------    
Math                5           3
Science             2           7
----------------    --------    --------    
Totals              6           8
```

What I would like to have:

```
Attendance for...

[Class]             [Jan 2]     [Jan 3]
----------------    --------    --------    
Math                5           3
Science             2           7
----------------    --------    --------    
Totals              7           10
```

I would like to sum the running total of CountDistinct(Student) and would think this should be simple within the SSRS matrix but no luck.  I have tried RunningValue for the Sum of CountDistinct(Student) by AttendanceDate (the Column Group) but am getting the distinct count of Students....

Is this kind of total possible using the matrix on detail-level data? Or would I need to aggregate the data first via a query, and then run the totals?

Any ideas to point me in the right direction are much appreciated.

Comment: Whilst it is possible to do this in SSRS, it's much simpler to do this in the dataset query. Simple get your dataset to return the distinct count values, then the matrix will just sum those values. If you struggle, post a sample of your data along with the expected result s that the sample data should give.

Comment: Got it.  I just was kind of hoping that there would be a nice clean way to do this in the matrix.  I need the underlying data (such are end-users, they will always want to validate!), so I figured maybe I could just use the matrix to summarize and the tablix for details of the same dataset.  Oh well!  Thanks for your response.